# Loop request in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve datas from an API. As the API can only accept one request at time, I'm struggling to implement the loop on my code.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.website.com/v1/"

payload="[{\"city\":\"\amsterdam", \"location_code\":2250, \"language_code\":\"en\"}]"

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myauthetificationabcd',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

url = "https://api.website.com/v1/"

payload="[{\"city\":\"\vienna", \"location_code\":2120, \"language_code\":\"de\"}]"

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myauthetificationabcd',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)


url = "https://api.website.com/v1/"

payload="[{\"city\":\"\paris", \"location_code\":2210, \"language_code\":\"en\"}]"

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myauthetificationabcd',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The code works that was as I'm getting output from the 3 requests response.text.

However,
I'd like to to create the loop where the payload will retrieve the data needed from a CSV or a .TXT file, with information such :

```
[{\"city\":\"\amsterdam", \"location_code\":2250, \"language_code\":\"en\"}]
[{\"city\":\"\vienna", \"location_code\":2120, \"language_code\":\"de\"}]
[{\"city\":\"\paris", \"location_code\":2210, \"language_code\":\"en\"}]
etc...
```

and save the output into a CSV file.

I already tried to combined the 3 set of requests, it works, but if I'm doing it for 100, it might not be simple.
So, creating a loop where data is load from a CSV or a .TXT file and save the output into another CSV document is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your request data in a dictionary you can do

```
import requests

url = "https://api.website.com/v1/"
payloads = {
    1: {'city': 'amsterdam', 'location_code': 2250, 'language_code': 'en'},
    2: {'city': 'vienna', 'location_code': 2120, 'language_code': 'de'}
}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myauthetificationabcd',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

for payload in payloads.values():
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks @po.pe, but I've already tried it and it's not working. The loop statement is not working as only the second one is executed unfortunately.

Comment: I found the issue, the line of print was not on the sale level than the response.